# Login form action issue in symfony2 traditional login form

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony2 and I created a form for user login, in the symfony site which is here:
[enter link description here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)
it say you don't need to handle the
`<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">`.
the sentence is: `You will not need to implement a controller for the /login_check URL as the firewall will automatically catch and process any form submitted to this URL.`
and the firewall will handle that automatically.
but when I use and submit the form it gives me this error:

`Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException`

my login.html.twig file is:

```
{% extends '::grid.html.twig' %}

{% block bContent %}
{% if error %}
<div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}
<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
<label for="username">Email :</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="account" />

<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

What should I do to correct the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [same documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html):

> New in version 2.1: As of Symfony 2.1, you must have routes configured
>   for your `login_path` and `check_path`. These keys can be route names (as
>   shown in this example) or URLs that have routes configured for them.

If you use the default values:

```
# app/config/security.yml
...
form_login:
    login_path:  login
    check_path:  login_check
```

You have to define the routes `login` & `login_check`.

Have you added them in `app/config/routing.yml` ?

```
# app/config/routing.yml
login:
    path:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeSecurityBundle:Security:login }
login_check:
    path:   /login_check
```

As you can see no controller is needed for `login_check`, as you've mentioned earlier:

> You will not need to implement a controller for the `/login_check` URL
>   as the firewall will automatically catch and process any form
>   submitted to this URL.

I think the error message mislead you:

> Unable to find the controller for path "`/login_check`". Maybe you
>   **forgot to add the matching route** in your routing configuration?

It's not the controller that Symfony2 cannot find, but the route itself `/login_check`.

Comment: That's true but it still not working. my routing is:                login_check:
    path:      /login_check

login:
    pattern:  /login/
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:login }

Comment: What's the error message now? Also try to remove the trailing `/` in `pattern: /login/` -> `pattern: /login`

Comment: the error is : Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

Comment: I have put the route in at the first, but it's still giving me the same error: login_check:
    path:     /login_check

Comment: try to remove the **route** `login_check` (from `routing.yml`) and replace `check_path: login_check` (route name) by `check_path: /login_check` (URL) in `security.yml`